# Why if a div contains an image that div do not have height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do the following page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <link href="estiles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1> GALERY OF IMAGES</h1>
        </div>
        <div id = "leftDiv">
            hola
        </div>

        <div id = "galery">
            <div id = "centerGalery">
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div>
                <div><img class = "imageGalery" src = "http://marcus.ridoutfamily.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/78186357b7074a1a3bda5d3c0ed4a2e0.jpg"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in which I have a header and two `divs`, one on the left and one on the right. Each one of the divs have 50% of the width of the body. Here there is any problem.

The problems comes when I want to add some images as a galery of photos in the div that it is on the right of the body. I want that all the images will be centered inside `galery` div but I could not achieve that (I created a new div that holds all the images). As opposed, I saw that the divs in which I have stored each image do not have height.

Is it normal? How, if the image it is contained inside the div, the div do not have height?

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#leftDiv{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}

#galery{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#centerGalery{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.imageGalery{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here it is what I mean:

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is going on coz of `float:left` on child nodes, just add overflow:hidden to parent `div`

Comment: @Smile0ff Do you mean to add `overflow:hidden` to `centerGalery`?

Comment: to image wrapper(div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are floating inside the container this means it won't know theres is content inside the container so it won't apply a height or a width.

http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/120/
updated your fiddle 
I added a class around the div that had the image inside and added `dispplay: inline-block` to it. And also removed the float: left on the imgs.

Comment: Further: nice explanation to explain why my divs did not have height. Very helpful to understand how it works. Nice! ;)